# SetText method not setting value in Modify Listener

Tags: swt

i have a requirement where the Text value should modify and set the modified value.
The Text Value is file path selected by the user.

```
txtPath.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

    @Override
                    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Text text= (Text)e.widget;                      
                        File fi= new File(text.getText());
                        text.setText(fi.getParent().toString());

                    }
                });
```

Iam getting an error in setting the value.

If user Selected path is "C:\test\folder\sample.xml"
The modify text path should be set with new value as "C:\test\folder"

Comment: Getting what error?

Comment: An error occured while setting the value is the error getting display in Dialog.IllegalArgumentException  is thrown

Comment: Add the full error with stacktrace to your question

Comment: ... and while you are at it, clean up and reformat the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

A modify event is triggered whenever the value changes--meaning for every keypress in the text field, and also by the setText() which you are calling. You probably want to listen for the focus lost event rather than the modify event.